# Como instalar MariaDB mediante un script en Inno Setup Compiler y evitar que genere 2 servicios?

Tags: windows, mariadb, servicio, instalacion, inno-setup

Contexto: Creación de un instalador para mi aplicación Net y base de datos MariaDB
El hacer un script desde Inno Setup Compiler para instalar MariaDB en Windows (mariadb-10.6.7-winx64.msi) con un nombre y puertos personalizados (MariaDB y puerto:2486), se instala bien mi servicio pero el problema es que además se instala un 2do servicio adicional llamado "MySQL" ocasionando conflicto. Como puedo evitar esto?

CODIGO:

```
[Run]
;*************************** INICIO MariaDB ********************************
Filename: msiexec.exe;  Parameters : " /i {tmp}\mariadb-10.6.7-winx64.msi SERVICENAME=MariaDB PORT=2486 ALLOWREMOTEROOTACCESS=1 ADDLOCAL=ALL REMOVE=HeidiSQL INSTALLDIR=""C:\MariaDB"" /qn";WorkingDir:{tmp}; StatusMsg: "Instalando Motor de Base de Datos..."; Description: "Instalar Motor de Base de Datos"; Flags: runhidden;
Filename: C:\MariaDB\bin\mysqld.exe; Parameters: --install-manual; WorkingDir: C:\MariaDB\bin; StatusMsg: Instalando Servicio MariaDB...; Flags: runhidden
Filename: net.exe; Parameters: start MariaDB; StatusMsg: Iniciando Servicio MariaDB;  Flags: runhidden
Filename: netsh; Parameters: firewall add portopening TCP 2486 MariaDB;  Flags: runhidden; StatusMsg: Habilitando puertos en el firewall...
```

Ya intenté mediante un instrucción dentro de mi script una vez que el servicio personalizado inicia, borrar  el 2do servicio, y lo hace bien. Los problemas se dan en las siguientes circunstancias al correr el instalador:

1. Si ya existe un servicio llamado "MySQL" previo a la instalación de MariaDB, se instala bien pero me deshabilita el servicio "MySQL" aun corriendo y al reiniciar el equipo lo termina de borrar, con la consiguiente pérdida de datos.
2. Si no existe previamente el servicio "MySQL", se crea el servicio "MariaDB" y también "MySQL", iniciándose en ese momento solo el servicio "MariaDB" y quedando el segundo "apagado" pero con arranque automático, para la siguiente ocasión que inicie el Windows. Todo funciona bien, hasta que se reinicia la computadora y automáticamente trata de iniciarse el servicio "MySql" primero en lugar de "MariaDB". Después de esto, aun borrando el servicio "MySQL" e iniciando manualmente "MariaDB" logra iniciar, con la consiguiente pérdida de datos.

Ya intenté mediante un instrucción dentro de mi script una vez que el servicio personalizado inicia, borrar  el 2do servicio, y lo hace bien.

CODIGO:

```
[Run]
;Borrando el servivio MySQL que MariaDB crea en automático 
Filename: "sc.exe"; Parameters: "delete MySQL"; StatusMsg: "Borrando MySQL service..."; Flags: runhidden
```

Lo ideal sería que desde el principio solo se instale 1 servicio (personalizado), para evitar que afecte  a otras aplicaciones y/o instancias de MySQL. Agradezco su atención.

Comment: Este no es un problema directamente de inno-setup. Si ejecutas el comando directamente en la consola ocurre el mismo efecto, cierto? De ser así, creo que lo que habría que encontrar es, o bien los parámetros que hay que pasar al instalador que estás ejecutando para que haga lo que quieres, o bien encontrar una versión del instalador de MariaDB que haga lo que buscas.

Comment: Así es, no considero que sea un problema de Inno Setup, más si de MariaDb, dado que si instalo directamente mariadb-10.6.7-winx64.msi , me pedirá tanto el nombre del servicio y del puerto y me creará solo esa instancia, sin duplicarla, sin embargo cuando le envío la misma información a través de parámetros, si me los acepta, pera a pesar de eso crear su propia instancia, debe ser un bug. Probaré con una versión más reciente. Gracias por comentar @jachguate